# How to pass the array value in to columns attribute of Jquery data table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I want to pass the variable to mColumns attributes instead of [0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9] , Here is my code :

```
$(function() {
 var table=$('#MSRRes').dataTable
( {

 "oTableTools": 
 {
    "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
    "aButtons": [
               {
                   "sExtends": "csv",
                   "mColumns": [0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                   "sAction":     "flash_save"

             }
    ]
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
var someArray=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

(function() {

var table=$('#MSRRes').dataTable ( {

 "oTableTools": 
 {
    "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
    "aButtons": [
               {
                   "sExtends": "csv",
                   "mColumns": someArray,
                   "sAction":     "flash_save"

             }
    ]
  }
});
});
```